# 'advancedBy' in Swift is unavailable

Tags: swift

[image: error messages]

I'm not sure how to resolve the above error messages, I have tried to convert it to index but it seems like it does not accept strings.

I'm not sure how `advancedBy` works too as well. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, `advancedBy()` has been renamed to `advanced(by: Int)`.

Additionally, `substringWithRange` has been renamed to `substring(with: Range)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error (sometimes more easily seen in the "Issues Navigator", by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>) says:

> error: 'advancedBy' is unavailable: To advance an index by n steps call 'index(_:offsetBy:)' on the CharacterView instance that produced the index.

Thus you could do:

```
let r = testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location) ..< testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location + range.length)
let result = testStr[r]
```

Or

```
let start = testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)
let end = testStr.index(start, offsetBy: range.length)
let result = testStr[start ..< end]
```